# How do I get the raw version of a gist from github?

Tags: gist

I need to load a shell script from a raw gist but I can't find a way to get raw URL.

```
curl -L address-to-raw-gist.sh | bash
```

Comment: Note: gist raw url just changed (February 2014). See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21984072/6309)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a permalink to the latest version of gist files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073096/is-there-a-permalink-to-the-latest-version-of-gist-files)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

And yet there is, look for the `raw` button (on the top-right of the source code).

The raw URL should look like this:

```
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/{user}/{gist_hash}/raw/{commit_hash}/{file}
```

Note: it is possible to get the latest version by omitting the `{commit_hash}` part, as shown below:

```
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/{user}/{gist_hash}/raw/{file}
```

Comment: While that link does get the raw , it is hard coded to that specific commit.

Comment: is there a possibility to get the *latest* raw version? If you omit the commit hash, it doesn't work neither...

Comment: @nerdoc Just omit the commit hash in the URL. e.g., https://gist.github.com/aymericbeaumet/940d6360efe5a4618302c291c7b2d051/#file-useful-es6-js would be accessed in a raw version as https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aymericbeaumet/940d6360efe5a4618302c291c7b2d051/raw/useful-es6.js

Comment: I thought that too, as it seems obvious. but it did not work. Tried, but did not work for me. Either there was a small (cache?) delay? I moved to [GitLab snippets](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/snippets.html), there it works as expected.

Comment: It should work, do you have a public gist to reproduce the issue?

Comment: [here](https://gist.github.com/nerdoc/b6a202fd8b06bae681a244df6298af72) is one. [raw second-last version with direct link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nerdoc/b6a202fd8b06bae681a244df6298af72/raw/d895749ccf88c6dc6707b9bf700a2f082fc4daa5/test.txt) - and the [latest version with a direct link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nerdoc/b6a202fd8b06bae681a244df6298af72/raw/66e6fc42e693904b54d86bbaf277d6368b32b429/test.txt) - these are 2 raw versions. but how do I get the latest **raw** version?

Comment: AAAARRRGGGHHH! https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nerdoc/b6a202fd8b06bae681a244df6298af72/raw/test.txt - I have to omit the commit hash, **but provide the filename afterwords**. So easy, but drove me nuts. Thanks.

Answer (score 30):

February 2014: the raw url just changed.
See "[Gist raw file URI change](http://developer.github.com/changes/2014-02-21-gist-raw-file-url-change/)":

> The raw host for all Gist files is changing immediately.
>   This change was made to further isolate user content from trusted GitHub applications.
>
> The new host is

```
 https://gist.githubusercontent.com.
```

> Existing URIs will redirect to the new host.

Before it was `https://gist.github.com/<username>/<gist-id>/raw/...`

Now it is `https://gist.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<gist-id>/raw/...`

For instance:

> https://gist.githubusercontent.com/VonC/9184693/raw/30d74d258442c7c65512eafab474568dd706c430/testNewGist

[KrisWebDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227298/kriswebdev) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589511/how-do-i-get-the-raw-version-of-a-gist-from-github/21984072?noredirect=1#comment39068089_21984072):

> If you want the last version of a Gist document, just remove the `<commit>/` from URL
>
> https://gist.githubusercontent.com/VonC/9184693/raw/testNewGist

Comment: @KrisWebDev good point. I have included in the answer for more visibility, along with an example.

Comment: `The raw host for all Gist files is changing immediately.`
But I found it not immediately

Comment: A better way would be also to pay attention to the API:
https://api.github.com/gists/9184693
You can get from there the raw_url and use that. This answere is correct, no doubt, but the API will (never) be outdated, it could be possible they change it again like in FEB 2014.

Answer (score 3):

One can simply use the github api.

```
https://api.github.com/gists/$GIST_ID
```

Reference: https://miguelpiedrafita.com/github-gists

Comment: This API returns JSON data, from which you can get the raw URL as follows: `url = json_data["files"][filename]["raw_url"]` where `filename` is the name of a specific file within the gist.

Answer (score 2):

Gitlab snippets provide short concise urls, are easy to create and goes well with the command line.

Sample example:  Enable bash completion by patching /etc/bash.bashrc

```
sudo su -
(curl -s https://gitlab.com/snippets/21846/raw && echo) | patch -s /etc/bash.bashrc
```