# GitHub Gist: RAW Permalink won't update

Tags: git, github

I have a URL to a gist, raw version but it won't always update. Say I get the raw link

```
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/username/27610b513177a762470ac95160c050fd/raw/f567a5ade06c9b8e7c101fe62fa3a4cac07e5bd7/test%2520gist
```

But I change the contents of that gist, the URL will change, the first link WONT include the changes.

```
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/username/27610b513177a762470ac95160c050fd/raw/60e3b421faa7e4e9ea6cd27e4a6ffd4809d3d40e/test%2520gist
```

How do I make 1 PERMANENT link that will forever include all the changes, not just the revision for that link?

I've tried with the ID, and just the id/raw but the ID isn't even a number like other people say, its more like a hash, can anyone help here?

**UPDATE:**

I've tried [the suggested answer], but it still *leads to the last revision*, does it have a delay in updating?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the raw version of a gist from github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589511/how-do-i-get-the-raw-version-of-a-gist-from-github)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a permalink to the latest version of gist files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073096/is-there-a-permalink-to-the-latest-version-of-gist-files)

Answer (score 9):

> the ID isn't even a number like other people say, its more like a hash

Yes, a [gist is a git repo](https://help.github.com/articles/about-gists/)

As [explained here](http://www.engel.io/2015-07-20-using-github-gists-as-config-store) by [Mark Engel](http://www.engel.io/):

> Imagine you want to host a json configuration file somewhere. You also don’t want to host it yourself, but would prefer to rely on a stable provider.
>
> You can use [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/) for this job.
>
> For example [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mren/17da9837f691acd2e8ae). You can see that there are 2 revisions.
>
> If you click on raw you get the current version
>
> - Version 1 https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mren/17da9837f691acd2e8ae/raw/9e26dfeeb6e641a33dae4961196235bdb965b21b/config.json
> - Version 2 https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mren/17da9837f691acd2e8ae/raw/afd0087d1b230bbc663ae4f4a1e9a1bc426d7eef/config.json
>
> In each version you see two hashes.
>
> - One hash is equal in both hashes. This is the hash of the gist
> - The other hash is the hash of the commit.
>
> **If you remove the last one the raw file always points to the latest revision**
>
> https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mren/17da9837f691acd2e8ae/raw/config.json

Comment: I've tried this, it still leads to the last revision, does it have a delay in updating? I'm confused.

Comment: @zhorachuI thought you wanted a permanent link to the latest revision: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mren/17da9837f691acd2e8ae/raw/config.json is one permanent URL that will always "include all the changes"

Comment: @zhorachu OK. I wasn't ware of that delay.

Answer (score 4):

Reviving this link to clarify the confusion.

Yes, VonC's answer is right,

> If you remove the last one the raw file always points to the latest revision

and,

> permanent URL ... will always "include all the changes"

However, it may do INDEED take some time to update.

Today, I was using **bit.ly** to shorten my permanent URL, but *found* it always points to the last/initial version that I set the short URL. So I have to give it up and try different URL shortening services. Only after trying two or three more did I realize that the problem is not at URL shortening service side but the gist permanent URL side -- confirmed by visiting the gist permanent URL directly, and --

it does take more than two or three minutes to update some times today, when I keep changing it to see what's wrong. But it does eventually change to the latest version as well. Confirmed by revisiting my bit.ly shortened URL as well.

Comment: Interesting addition to my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

For those that may need a programmatic solution (*e.g.* dynamically editing/updating a gist during web scraping)...

As of May 2021, a workaround to avoid the delay associated with the cache of the last commit is using the URL associated with the "Raw" button of the UI, shown below.

[image: RawButton]

- The URL of interest will be of the format: `https://gist.github.com/{user}/{gist_hash}/raw/{commit_hash}/{filename}`
- If you parse the DOM for the link associated with this button, you can bypass the 2-3 minute delay normally associated with using the link of the format: `https://gist.github.com/{user}/{gist_hash}/raw`
- Sample code to retrieve this link in Python would look something like the following:

#### Script to retrieve raw gist link (bypasses cache-related wait time)

```py
# Python 3.9.1
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

repo_url = f'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/{user}/{gist_hash}'
html = requests.get(repo_url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
button = soup.find_all('div', class_='file-actions flex-order-2 pt-0') # Finds "Raw" button
raw_url = f"https://gist.github.com/{button[0].contents[1].attrs['href'][1:]}"
```

```py
> print(raw_url)

'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/{user}/{gist_hash}/raw/{commit_hash}/{filename}'
```